# I would like to remove a java process in the system tray called LRAT

Tags: windows-7, java, notification-area

I would like to remove a java process in the system tray called LRAT.

When I right-click on the icon there is no context menu and no exit option.  When I double-click on it, nothing seems to happen.

I noticed it first after I updated the Adobe Flash player plugin, but I doubt it had anything to do with it.

Nothing in the Process Explorer is called LRAT, and a search on the net produce nothing except links to RAT Trojan horse.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Start killing processes until you find the one that makes the Icon go away.